# Flutter convert Image to base64 and base64 String to Image

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

Hello i want to convert a Image to a base64 String and then convert it back to an Image.
This is how I did it:

```
 File pickedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery
    );
 List<int> test = pickedImage.readAsBytesSync();
 String test2 = base64Encode(test);
 Uint8List test3 = base64Decode(test2);
 File test4 = new File.fromRawPath(test3);
 FirebaseVisionImage ourImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(test4);
```

I get a error and when i want to print test4 i get only questionmarks. When I print pickedImage I get this:

```
File: '/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20190503-WA0005.jpg'
```

Comment: The bytes that `File.fromRawPath` takes are *not* the *contents* of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be doing all the work already for converting an image into base64 and back:

```
List<int> imageBytes = pickedImage.readAsBytesSync();
String imageB64 = base64Encode(imageBytes);
Uint8List decoded = base64Decode(imageB64);
```

As far as using it for your `FirebaseVisionImage`, I'm not sure how much I can help as I have no experience with that class (I'm assuming you're using the firebase_ml_vision library). However, looking at the [source](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_ml_vision/lib/src/firebase_vision.dart) for `FirebaseVisionImage`, there is a factory constructor for `fromBytes` as well as `fromFile`, though it's a bit more complicated to use. If you can get it to work, though, that would probably be the more appropriate constructor for your needs:

```
// Metadata values based on an RGBA-encoded 1920x1080 image
// You will have to change these values to fit your specific images
final planeMetadata = FirebaseVisionImagePlaneMetadata(
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    bytesPerRow: 1920 * 4,
);

final metadata = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata(
    size: Size(1920, 1080),
    planeData: planeMetadata,

    // From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers?language=objc
    // kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA
    rawFormat: 'RGBA', 
);

final visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(decoded, metadata);
```

Alternatively, you could just save the bytes to a temporary file and use that:

```
// Assuming the source image is a PNG image
File imgFile = File('tempimage.png');
imgFile.writeAsBytesSync(decoded.ToList());

final visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(imgFile);
```