# Convert base64 string to Image class and back

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I have a simple table, which I would like to create and maintain via **MOOR**. Below is the table definition:

```
class Plants extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get name => text()();
  TextColumn get image => text().map(const ImageConverter()).nullable()();
}
```

As you can see, I have an `image` field, and I would like to use `Image` to `base64` conversion and back. Please, note I refer to Flutter [Image class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html), not the widget.
I already found [the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977615/flutter-convert-image-to-base64-and-base64-string-to-image), where conversion between **Image widget** and **base64** took place, but it does not seem to me right from an architectural point of view to use widget on the data layer.
This is what I have done so far:

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:moor/moor.dart';

class ImageConverter extends TypeConverter<Image, String> {
  Image _imageFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return null; // <--- missing implementation
  }

  Uint8List _dataFromBase64String(String base64String) {
    return base64Decode(base64String);
  }

  String _base64String(Uint8List data) {
    return base64Encode(data);
  }

  const ImageConverter();
  @override
  Image mapToDart(String fromDb) {
    if (fromDb == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return _imageFromBase64String(fromDb);
  }

  @override
  String mapToSql(Image value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return _base64String(value.getBytes());
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have no problem (I guess) to implement `Image` to `base64` conversion, I struggle however to implement `base64` to `Image`.

Comment: Wouldn't you create a codec using instantiateImageCodec, wait for getNextFrame, and extract the image from that? Note that to do that you'd need to be sure to encode the image bytes into PNG to preserve stuff like the geometry. Where does getBytes come from? Does image have such a method?

Comment: Would you provide a code snippet with regard to your proposal? Yes, `getBytes` comes from [Image class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/image/Image/getBytes.html)

Comment: I only see `toByteData`. Can you provide a link showing this other method?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image/getBytes.html that's from yet another Image class, not the one you provided the link to.

Comment: Yup, my falt, your link is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the link in the question is incorrect. The question refers to the `Image` class from the `image` package - see https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image-class.html

You need a pair of functions like this:

```
Image b64ToImage(int width, int height, String b64) {
  return Image.fromBytes(width, height, base64.decode(b64));
}

String imageToB64(Image image) => base64.encode(image.getBytes());
```

`getBytes` returns you an array of NxM 32 bit pixels (by default in RGBA order) but gives you no idea of the geometry of the image. A 100x200 image will return an 80,000 byte array - but so will a 200x100 image! When you re-construct the image you need to tell it the original width and height.

This is why file formats like BMP exist. They prefix the pixel array with a header that contain information like width, height, pixel depth, pixel order, etc. The package has a BMP decoder, but no encoder. You could implement a simple BMP encoder if you wanted to encode the width and height into the byte array and thus into the base64 string. (See this [partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51315442/use-ui-decodeimagefromlist-to-display-an-image-created-from-a-list-of-bytes/51316489#51316489).)